# Create moderation for form data

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to add moderation logic for a form which has name, mail and comment. Now when anyone fills the form and clicks "submit" it should directly be posted to the page. I want to send the content to "admin" and to be published after the content is reviewed. How can I achieve this in Drupal? I'm using Drupal 7.2.

Comment: tried wenform.but dont know how to moderate

Comment: I want to send the field value to mail.but not to be displayed in view page

Comment: This would only be an admin view. You decide what to display in that view exactly.

Comment: I want to display only approved comments by admin

Comment: Then build a view that only displays approved comments.

Comment: I have add the filter criteria as Webform: Node (= ) in view page

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. I guess you are looking for a site-builder approach.

Then you may have a look at the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. Webform lets you build forms and define e-mail addresses to where the submitted data should be send to.

Then there is the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module with which you can define a rule that on every form submission automatically a (initially unpublished) node is being created populated with the form values.

And finally you may provide a list of all unpublished nodes built with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Maybe you already provide a button "publish" next to each node in the list that triggers the node publication.

---

Alternatively you may also have a look at moderation modules like [Workbench Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation).

Or have a look at the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module which is pretty useful for flagging content according some logic and/or button clicks. For example you can add a flag: approved.

Comment: how to create view for webform

Comment: I have created a fields emailtest in webform content type and create content for that content type.In view include the field emailtest but email is not previewed in view page